# python if else not working after refactoring

Tags: python

```
def binary(val):
return str(val) if val<=1 else binary(val>>1) + str(val&1)
```

how can I rewrite this code

i Have tried:

```
if (val<=1) :
return str(val)
else 
binary(val>>1) + str(val)
```

but it does not work

Comment: you need to add `return` too in your `else` block. Also, fix the indentation if this is how your actual code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `'return'`, a colon `':'`,  `'&1'`. And that is not considering the indentation:

```
if val <= 1:
    return str(val)
else:
    return binary(val >> 1) + str(val & 1)
```

Comment: it says invalid syntax on `else:`